# Is this a true pink noise generator?

Tags: audio, noise-spectral-density

I found [this neat circuit](http://schematicsforfree.com/archive/file/Oscillators%20and%20Generators/Pink-White%20&%20Other%20Noise%20Generators/Pink%20&%20White%20Noise%20Generators%20-%20Misc.pdf) (page 18/62) but I don't understand it.

This doesn't seem to be your usual white noise generator plus pink -3db/octave filter. Is this a true pink noise generator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The circuit you reference actually does work by generating white noise and then filtering it to make it pink.
Capacitor C2 (according to the description in the text on the same page as the schematic) provides the -3dB/per octave low pass needed to make pink noise out of white noise - R3 and C2 together form a lowpass filter with a cutoff of around 300Hz.

Q1 generates white noise through the BE junction.  Q2 amplifies it, and C2 (with R3) filters it.

Don't use this circuit with a normal earphone.  The text specifies a crystal earphone.  You need this because the output is very high impedance.  To use this circuit with a regular earphone you would need another amplifier stage with a low output impedance.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: There is one big flaw in this circuit associated with Q1 but I'll leave it to the OP to find that as he thinks I'm wasting people's time LOL.

Comment: @Andyaka -  I don't see it.  I can see what it is supposed to do, but I don't know enough to find the gotchas.

Comment: @Andyaka, Zenering the BE junction of a transistor is a well known noise source.  (The one meg will limit the current.)  But maybe you see some other flaw?  To the OP,  Old carbon comp resistors make very nice 1/f noise sources... you have to put a current through them.

Comment: On power up, until the 2nd transistor achieves DC equilibrium and C1 becomes properly charged, the impedance across the 1M resistor will be a matter of a few hundred ohms. The maximum rated reverse B-E voltage for the first transistor is 5 volts and the circuit is powered from an 18 volt supply.

Comment: Mmmmpf.  Yeah.  So, do we figure that Q1 is going to go "pop" at some point?

Comment: "provides the -3dB/per octave low pass"  There is no such thing.  First-order filters fall off at 6 dB/oct (integrator), producing Brownian/red noise, and you can't easily make fractional-order filters ([because it requires infinite knowledge of the signal?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus#Nature_of_the_fractional_derivative)), so "pinking filters" involve lots of 6 dB filters arranged to *approximate* a 3 dB fall-off rate.  Maybe the circuit intentionally generates lots of pink flicker noise and amplifies it?